# Use of defvar in straight.el's bootstrapping

Tags: variables, defvar, straight.el

The package `straight.el` requires the following bootstrapping code in your emacs config:

```
(defvar bootstrap-version)
(let ((bootstrap-file
       (expand-file-name "straight/repos/straight.el/bootstrap.el" user-emacs-directory))
      (bootstrap-version 5))
  (unless (file-exists-p bootstrap-file)
    (with-current-buffer
        (url-retrieve-synchronously
         "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/raxod502/straight.el/develop/install.el"
         'silent 'inhibit-cookies)
      (goto-char (point-max))
      (eval-print-last-sexp)))
  (load bootstrap-file nil 'nomessage))
```

The use of `defvar` to initialize `bootstrap-version` was a little confusing to me, given that it's only used in a `let` statement that could have also just as easily initialized and defined it. However, it is invoked later in the `install.el` file that is retrieved into the buffer later. I'm not confident I fully understand the use of `defvar`, but is it the case that initializing `bootstrap-version` using a `defvar` statement makes it available to `install.el`? Would it not be accessible otherwise? If that's not the case, why is this variable initialized in this way instead of in the `let` expression?

Answer (score 3):

The form `(defvar bootstrap-version)` doesn't set the value of `bootstrap-version`, and will not over-write the value of `bootstrap-version` if it was already set. It is also not necessary to make the variable "available" to `straight.el` or any of the files it includes.

The only thing the defvar accomplishes here is to declare `bootstrap-version` as "special", meaning that it is treated as a dynamic variable. `straight.el` uses lexical binding, so without this declaration `bootstrap-version` would be lexically bound.

To understand the difference, you might find [Dynamic vs Lexical Binding](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DynamicBindingVsLexicalBinding#h5o-3) helpful.